# Rudin Analysis: order in set of rationals

Tags: analysis

In Rudin's Analysis, chapter 1, page 3, definition 1.6 states

> $\mathbb Q$ is an ordered set if $r<s$ is defined to mean that $s-r$ is a positive rational number.

But the very definition of 'positive' requires the notion of greater than or less than, so it seems all circular to me.

Comment: if you can distinguish $\Bbb N$ from $\Bbb Z,$ you can distinguish positive from negative ($\Bbb Q$ can be defined as ratios)

Comment: You are right I guess. The problem is Rudin does not build the rationals axiomatically, and for a beginner like me it is hard(impossible) to know what assumptions to take. Should I study Tao first?

Answer (score 0):

**Original Answer** No.  We have what a "positive rational number" means (it is the quotient of a positive integer by another positive integer), but we don't yet have the ordering $<\subseteq\mathbb{Q}^2$.  This definition defines the ordering on $\mathbb{Q}$.

---

**Addendum** OK, checking my copy of baby Rudin.  Definition 1.6 is

> **1.6 Definition** An *ordered set* is a set $S$ in which an order is defined.

What you quoted isn't Definition 1.6, but an example in the paragraph after Definition 1.6.  Anyway, the circularity is avoided if you do it properly as suggested in my original answer.

Comment: How do we know what a positive rational number means without first defining the notion of inquality?

Comment: He isn't defining inequality.  The $<$ sign in definition $1.5$ refers to a general order relation.  The remark  just means that the ordinary  relation < on the rationals, which you are presumed to be familiar with, is in fact an order relation.

Comment: @ShiladityaMukherjee We have a definition of "positive rational number" without first defining the notion of inequality.  We construct $\mathbb{Z}$ from $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ from $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$ as ordered pairs (and ordered pairs of ordered pairs) and we have constructed an ordering on $\mathbb{Z}$ along the way, so we can talk about "represented by a positive integer divided by another positive integer" as definition of positive rational number.

Comment: @saulspatz We are not assumed to be familiar with the notion of inequality among rationals. Read the question.

Comment: @user Should I do T.Tao Analysis first?

Comment: @ShiladityaMukherjee 1, Don't be rude.  2. I've not only read the question, I've read the book, and understood it.

Comment: @ShiladityaMukherjee Probably the first four chapters of Tao's book (i.e., up to construction and properties of $\mathbb{Q}$) or something like A.G. Hamilton's *Numbers, Sets and Axioms: The apparatus of Mathematics*.  Then both Tao and baby Rudin start covering the same material in more-or-less the same order, and which one to read depends on what you like.

Comment: @user10354138 thanks a lot.

Comment: @saulspatz sorry. But we are NOT assumed to be familiar because the example *defines* the meaning of ">".

Comment: No, I think you misinterpret the example, as I said.  It's true that the same symbol is used for the usual order on the rationals, and the generic order symbol that Rudin is talking about.  All he's saying though, is "The usual order on the rationals is an order in the sense of Definition 1.5."  He isn't *defining* the meaning of a positive number here.  It would be clearer if he'd used other symbol  like $\prec$ in the definition.  Then he could have said, "$r\prec s$ if and only if $s-r$ is positive, is an order on $\mathbb{Q}$."

Answer (score 0):

You can define a positive rational number with an algebraic property : it is a rational number which is a non zero square of a real number. That is why he is doing this.

EDIT : sorry, it is not a natural way to do it, since we construct $\mathbb{R}$ after $\mathbb{Q}$. So, the natural way is to say that a rational $p/q = (p,q)$ (rational defined by a equivalence relation on 2-uplets) is positive if $p$ and $q$ are positive, or $p$ and $q$ are negative.

Comment: You can probably do it in a million other ways, once you first go through the axiomatic approach, for which you have to do Analysis first, for which you have to study Rudin..

Answer (score 0):

The positive rational numbers can be defined without reference to order by

1. $1\in \mathbb Q^+$
2. $a,b\in \mathbb Q^+ \rightarrow a+b\in\mathbb Q^+\land ab^{-1}\in\mathbb Q^+$
3. $a\in \mathbb Q^+ \rightarrow -a\notin \mathbb Q^+$

1 and 2 ensure $\mathbb Q^+$ contains all positive rationals: any positive rational can be written as the ratio of two positive integers, which can themselves be written as finite sums of $1$s. 3 then ensures that no negative rationals or $0$ can be elements of $\mathbb Q^+$.

Answer (score 0):

I have an analysis textbook which lays out axioms for the Reals, in which the term 'positive' is an undefined term satisfying the following axioms:

1) For any Real number r, one of the following mutually-exclusive conditions holds: (a) r is positive; (b) r is zero; (c) -r is positive.

2) Any finite sum of positive Real numbers is positive, and any finite product of positive Real numbers is positive.

From these it is not too hard to prove basic properties of positive numbers, e.g: 1 is positive; -1 is NOT positive; N is positive for each natural number N; etc.  Then the ordering r < s (for Real r, s) is DEFINED by '(s - r) is positive'.  No circularity.